# GridView doesn't display columns or empty records text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Stored Procedure that returns a data including column names. Below is what is returned on an empty stored procedure.

[image]

My gridview only displays the column headers when there is data returned.

It does **NOT** display the column headers `(ShowHeaderWhenEmpty)` OR the no records found `(EmptyDataText)` when the datatable is 0.

```
protected void populateTableData(GridView gv, DataTable dt) {
            //CLEAR ANY PREVIOUS DATA
            gv.DataSource = null;
            gv.DataBind();

            //LOAD NEW DATA
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
            gv.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true; 
            gv.EmptyDataText = "No records where found.";

            //REQUIRED FOR BOOTSTRAP TO MAKE THE TABLE LOOK CORRECTLY
            gv.UseAccessibleHeader = true;

        }
```

Here is my gridview from the aspx side:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvFees" GridLines="None" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowDataBound="gvFees_RowDataBound" ></asp:GridView>
```

What am I doing wrong? I would prefer a code-behind solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `DataBind()` call to the end. You bind the data before you are setting the options for showing the header.

```
protected void populateTableData(GridView gv, DataTable dt)
{
    //CLEAR ANY PREVIOUS DATA
    gv.DataSource = null;
    gv.DataBind();

    //LOAD NEW DATA
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
    gv.EmptyDataText = "No records where found.";

    //REQUIRED FOR BOOTSTRAP TO MAKE THE TABLE LOOK CORRECTLY
    gv.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Sigh, it is always something simple!

Comment: It sure always seems that way